# Почему срабатывают не все коллбеки при загрузке изображений с бэка?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я использую AsyncImage для загрузки изображения с бэка:

```
@Composable
fun BannerReference(
    iconUrl: String? = null,
    iconUrlFromRes: Int? = null,
    onImageLoadingState: (State) -> Unit = {}
) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = iconUrl ?: iconUrlFromRes,
            onLoading = {
                Log.d("debuggg", "onLoading")
                onImageLoadingState.invoke(it)
                        },
            onSuccess = {
                Log.d("debuggg", "onSuccess")
                onImageLoadingState.invoke(it)
                        },
            onError = {
                Log.d("debuggg", "onError")
                onImageLoadingState.invoke(it)
                      },
            contentDescription = null,
        )
}
```

Эту Composable функцию я вызываю в другой функции несколько раз в цикле:

```
referralProgramsData.mgmParams.products.forEachIndexed { index, product ->

            BannerReference(
                iconUrl = product.bannerImage,
                iconUrlFromRes = getBannerImagePlaceholder(product.type),
                onImageLoadingState = { state ->
                    Log.d("debuggg", "screen state: ${state}")
                    imageLoadingState.invoke(ImageLoadingStatuses(index, state))
                }
            )
        }
```

Если я вызываю BannerReference в цикле 2 или более раз, иногда я получаю такие логи (логи ниже получены для двух вызовов BannerReference в цикле):

```
2023-08-01 12:03:14.951  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onLoading
2023-08-01 12:03:14.951  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Loading(painter=null)
2023-08-01 12:03:14.967  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onLoading
2023-08-01 12:03:14.967  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Loading(painter=null)
2023-08-01 12:03:15.078  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onError
2023-08-01 12:03:15.078  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Error(painter=null, result=coil.request.ErrorResult@f10cd10e)
```

То есть onError должен вызваться дважды, но по какой-то причине не срабатывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем такое может быть связано и как решить эту проблему? В какую сторону копать?